# run multiple .exe files at the same time using python

Tags: python

I want to open multiple .exe files using python scripts but it won't open next .exe or file without closing the previous one. I want to open all of them at once.

Here is my code

```
    import os
    os.chdir( 'C:\\Users\\FOLDER\\' )
    os.system( '"C:\\Users\\FOLDER\\APP.exe"' )
    os.chdir( 'C:\\Users\\FOLDER2\\' )
    os.system('"C:\\Users\\FOLDER2\\APP2.xlsx"')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [python `multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html), this is an example from the documentation, which you can quickly adapt to your needs:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5)
def f(x):
    return x*x
p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

Comment: The question is not about multithreading but about how to run non-blocking programs.